# Check if comments are turned off or on using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, comments

There is an option to turn off the comments in a SharePoint modern pages.

Is it possible to check whether the comments is turned off or not using REST?

Comment: Do you need the solution using REST API only or you can use PowerShell as well?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we could use the below api to get comments for a modern page：

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Site Pages')/items(1)/comments
```

There is no such api to check if the comments is turned off or not.

Reference:
http://sharepoint-lakku.blogspot.com/p/restendpoints.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Site Pages')/GetItemById(<Insert Page ID here>)/CommentsDisabled
```

This REST call returns a boolean value